# Is there a way to see if a statement is True during a give time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been playing around with the raspberry pi for a bit now and was trying to do a small project. I want my program to recognize when a button is pressed during a given time, i.e 1 seconds, then light up an LED.

My attempt was to see if the button was pressed (True), then make the program sleep for 2 seconds, and see if it is still true. This did work but not as efficiently I wanted it to. Is there a way to see if a statement remains True for a given time?

edit: more information about my setup and code.
I've dissembled an old flashlight, and taken the button from it. The Button does have a two metal pieces on the sides, that i have connected to one GND cable and the other the a 1k ohm resistor and a gpio cable. When i tried the following code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
from time import sleep

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(19, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(11, gpio.OUT)

try:
    while True:
        if gpio.input(19) == 1:
            sleep(0.05)
            if gpio.input(19) == 1:
                sleep(0.05)
                if gpio.input(19) == 1:
                    print("on")
                    gpio.output(11, True)
        else:
            print("off")
            gpio.output(11, False)
            sleep(0.1)
        
finally:
    print("\nInterrupted.\nCleaning code")
    gpio.cleanup()
```

Im aware of how gross this code looks, i'm terribly sorry. The reason for the triple if statement was to see if the code returns "on" in 3 different lines after another. This is because for some reason when the input value of the button "is set to" 0, it is actually jumping around 1 and 0 for some reason. This leads to it returning "On \nOff \nOn etc". My thought was if this prints "on" 3 times in a row then this must be on the stable side, so turn the LED on, else turn it off. This works but i'm not really happy with the code. If there was a way for me to see if it is "on" for a second or two then this must be the stable side and i can turn the LED on. And it would make my code in the future of making something similar, include a lot less if statements for a cleaner looking code.

Comment: Does the button not support event listeners?

Comment: Have you tried polling the time in a while loop?  It seems like with this sleep method, the user can release the button in between and press it again before the 2 seconds and this button should still work.

Comment: Im sorry, but i do not understand. What is change listener? The button i'm using is a simple toggle button that i found from an old flashlight. When clicked, the input value is either 1 or 2.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  In particular, you need to specify your system well enough for us to comment on your problem.  An old flashlight button does not, per se, have any Python interface -- so far, your question has far too many unimplemented and unspecified components.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: does this look better?

Comment: I think you are seeing switch bounce which is a universal problem with almost all physical contact switches, button, relays, etc.   Instead of using sleep, you should use the timer value.  When you first see a switch "made" store the value of the timer.  Then in a while loop wait for the switch to be "unmade" or for the system time to exceed your debounce time.  Then you call it a good switch.  If it becomes unmade before the time, ignore it.  google something like:  `python switch debounce` or something along those lines.  If you don't find an answer, I could put some code here.